# Why the bootstrap toogle isnt working on my code?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

So, the toogle isnt working but i dont know why since i think i have the order of jquery and bootstrap corret. I saw that people were having problems in this but what i said before would be sufficient.

**CSS**

```
'''
    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #index {
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url("https://images5.alphacoders.com/317/thumb-1920-317664.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100vh;
        opacity:80%;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: rgba(255,99,71,0);
    }
```

**HTML**
EDIT: I forgot to put here -- body id="index"

'''

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-opacity-10 fixed-top py-3">
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="color:red">
            <img style="height:50px; width:65px;" src="img/f1-abu-dhabi-gp-2017-f1-logo-6614911-       removebg-preview.png" />
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="home.html" style="color:white"><b>Home</b></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Circuits.html" style="color: white"><b>Circuits</b></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Drivers.html" style="color: white"><b>Drivers</b></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Timeline.html" style="color: white"><b>Champions</b></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a style="color: white" class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a style="color:white" class="dropdown-item" href="FAQs.html"><b>FAQ's</b></a></li>
                <li><a style="color:white" class="dropdown-item" href="AboutUs.html"><b>About us</b></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you loading jquery 2 times?

Comment: Done, (i think i done ctrl z and didnt notice that)

Comment: it would be good if you put your code in a jsfiddle or codepen so we could just duplicate it and fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the trigger id to the `class="collapse navbar-collapse"`.

You used `data-bs-target="#navbarScroll"` as your attribute

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

You just need to add the `id` attribute in order for it to find and trigger your dropdown.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
```

If you want to use class then use it like this `data-bs-target=".navbarScroll"` as your attribute

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarScroll">
```

You can also check working pen here https://codepen.io/Preygremmer15/pen/GROpjPo